# Does anyone have a "\newrgbcolor{colourname}{x.x.x}" list?

Tags: color

When I want to use colours in LaTeX, I normally use this colour chart of predefined colours that LaTeX knows by name:

[image]

However, I've recently needed to use `pstricks` (I think it's called) and to use colours (at least in the template I'm working with) I need to type in RGB values, which is unsatisfactory.

Does anyone know of a nice big list like the one below but for RBG values?

Here is a MWE of a template I'm using:

```
\documentclass[landscape,a0b,final]{a0poster}

\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-grad}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Definition of some variables and colors
%\renewcommand{\rho}{\varrho}
%\renewcommand{\phi}{\varphi}
\setlength{\columnsep}{6cm}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{1.5mm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.0cm}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%               Background                     %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand{\background}[3]{
\newrgbcolor{cgradbegin}{#1}
\newrgbcolor{cgradend}{#2}
\psframe[fillstyle=gradient,gradend=cgradend,
gradbegin=cgradbegin,gradmidpoint=#3](0.,0.)(1.\textwidth,-1.\textheight)
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%                Poster                        %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newenvironment{poster}{
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.95\textwidth}
}{
\end{minipage} 
\end{center}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%                pcolumn                       %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newenvironment{pcolumn}[1]{
\begin{minipage}{#1\textwidth}
\begin{center}
}{
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%                pbox                          %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newrgbcolor{lcolor}{0. 0. 0.80}
\newrgbcolor{gcolor1}{1. 1. 1.}
\newrgbcolor{gcolor2}{.80 .80 1.}

\newcommand{\pbox}[4]{
\psshadowbox[#3]{
\begin{minipage}[t][#2][t]{#1}
#4
\end{minipage}
}}

%=======================================================================

\usepackage{eso-pic}
\newcommand\BackgroundPic{
\put(10,-50){
\parbox[b][\paperheight]{\paperwidth}{%
\vfill
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight,
keepaspectratio]{TheSun2.eps}\vfill}}}

\begin{document}

\AddToShipoutPicture{\BackgroundPic}

%\background{1. 1. 1.}{1. 1. 1.}{0.5}

\vspace*{2cm}

\newrgbcolor{lightblue}{0. 0. 0.80}
\newrgbcolor{white}{1. 1. 1.}
\newrgbcolor{whiteblue}{.80 .80 1.}

\newrgbcolor{brightblue}{0.310 0.749 1}

\begin{poster}

%=======================================================================

\vspace*{2cm}

%%% Begin of Multicols-Enviroment
\begin{multicols}{3}

%%% SECTION 1
\begin{center}\pbox{0.8\columnwidth}{}{linewidth=2mm,framearc=0.1,linecolor=lightblue,fillstyle=gradient,gradangle=180,gradbegin=    white,gradend=whiteblue,gradmidpoint=1.0,framesep=1em}{\begin{center}     \textbf{Introduction} \end{center}}\end{center}\vspace{1.25cm}

Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla.

%=========================================================================

\end{multicols}
\end{poster}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Really? Why doesn't it allow you to use names? Perhaps create a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) showing this.

Comment: I am pretty sure LaTeX doesn't know about color by default, but rather you need to either load the `color` or `xcolor` package. Can you provide a MWE showing what you are trying to do?

Comment: @Werner I have added a MWE. Is there any other information that I can provide to help?

Comment: Have you checked files `svgnam.def`, `x11nam.def` in `texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Add the package [`xcolor`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) to your document preamble. It provides a number of named colours, depending on the package option you specify. From section **4 Colours by name** in the [`xcolor` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/xcolor/xcolor.pdf) (p 38 onward):

[image: basic colours]

[image: dvipsnames]

[image: svgnames]

[image: x11names]

Of course, you also have the luxury of specifying colours using mixtures (like `blue!50!green` which is 50% blue and 50% green).

If, even at this stage, you're still bound to an RGB format, open [`xcolor.dtx](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/xcolor/xcolor.dtx) and search for the named colours, where you will find their exact RGB components. For the last two colour sets, here they are:

#### `svgnames`:

```
                         R         G         B
--------------------------------------------------
AliceBlue                0.94      0.972     1         
AntiqueWhite             0.98      0.92      0.844     
Aqua                     0         1         1         
Aquamarine               0.498     1         0.83      
Azure                    0.94      1         1         
Beige                    0.96      0.96      0.864     
Bisque                   1         0.894     0.77      
Black                    0         0         0         
BlanchedAlmond           1         0.92      0.804     
Blue                     0         0         1         
BlueViolet               0.54      0.17      0.888     
Brown                    0.648     0.165     0.165     
BurlyWood                0.87      0.72      0.53      
CadetBlue                0.372     0.62      0.628     
Chartreuse               0.498     1         0         
Chocolate                0.824     0.41      0.116     
Coral                    1         0.498     0.312     
CornflowerBlue           0.392     0.585     0.93      
Cornsilk                 1         0.972     0.864     
Crimson                  0.864     0.08      0.235     
Cyan                     0         1         1         
DarkBlue                 0         0         0.545     
DarkCyan                 0         0.545     0.545     
DarkGoldenrod            0.72      0.525     0.044     
DarkGray                 0.664     0.664     0.664     
DarkGreen                0         0.392     0         
DarkGrey                 0.664     0.664     0.664     
DarkKhaki                0.74      0.716     0.42      
DarkMagenta              0.545     0         0.545     
DarkOliveGreen           0.332     0.42      0.185     
DarkOrange               1         0.55      0         
DarkOrchid               0.6       0.196     0.8       
DarkRed                  0.545     0         0         
DarkSalmon               0.912     0.59      0.48      
DarkSeaGreen             0.56      0.736     0.56      
DarkSlateBlue            0.284     0.24      0.545     
DarkSlateGray            0.185     0.31      0.31      
DarkSlateGrey            0.185     0.31      0.31      
DarkTurquoise            0         0.808     0.82      
DarkViolet               0.58      0         0.828     
DeepPink                 1         0.08      0.576     
DeepSkyBlue              0         0.75      1         
DimGray                  0.41      0.41      0.41      
DimGrey                  0.41      0.41      0.41      
DodgerBlue               0.116     0.565     1         
FireBrick                0.698     0.132     0.132     
FloralWhite              1         0.98      0.94      
ForestGreen              0.132     0.545     0.132     
Fuchsia                  1         0         1         
Gainsboro                0.864     0.864     0.864     
GhostWhite               0.972     0.972     1         
Gold                     1         0.844     0         
Goldenrod                0.855     0.648     0.125     
Gray                     0.5       0.5       0.5       
Green                    0         0.5       0         
GreenYellow              0.68      1         0.185     
Grey                     0.5       0.5       0.5       
Honeydew                 0.94      1         0.94      
HotPink                  1         0.41      0.705     
IndianRed                0.804     0.36      0.36      
Indigo                   0.294     0         0.51      
Ivory                    1         1         0.94      
Khaki                    0.94      0.9       0.55      
Lavender                 0.9       0.9       0.98      
LavenderBlush            1         0.94      0.96      
LawnGreen                0.488     0.99      0         
LemonChiffon             1         0.98      0.804     
LightBlue                0.68      0.848     0.9       
LightCoral               0.94      0.5       0.5       
LightCyan                0.88      1         1         
LightGoldenrod           0.933     0.867     0.51      
LightGoldenrodYellow     0.98      0.98      0.824     
LightGray                0.828     0.828     0.828     
LightGreen               0.565     0.932     0.565     
LightGrey                0.828     0.828     0.828     
LightPink                1         0.712     0.756     
LightSalmon              1         0.628     0.48      
LightSeaGreen            0.125     0.698     0.668     
LightSkyBlue             0.53      0.808     0.98      
LightSlateBlue           0.518     0.44      1         
LightSlateGray           0.468     0.532     0.6       
LightSlateGrey           0.468     0.532     0.6       
LightSteelBlue           0.69      0.77      0.87      
LightYellow              1         1         0.88      
Lime                     0         1         0         
LimeGreen                0.196     0.804     0.196     
Linen                    0.98      0.94      0.9       
Magenta                  1         0         1         
Maroon                   0.5       0         0         
MediumAquamarine         0.4       0.804     0.668     
MediumBlue               0         0         0.804     
MediumOrchid             0.73      0.332     0.828     
MediumPurple             0.576     0.44      0.86      
MediumSeaGreen           0.235     0.7       0.444     
MediumSlateBlue          0.484     0.408     0.932     
MediumSpringGreen        0         0.98      0.604     
MediumTurquoise          0.284     0.82      0.8       
MediumVioletRed          0.78      0.084     0.52      
MidnightBlue             0.098     0.098     0.44      
MintCream                0.96      1         0.98      
MistyRose                1         0.894     0.884     
Moccasin                 1         0.894     0.71      
NavajoWhite              1         0.87      0.68      
Navy                     0         0         0.5       
NavyBlue                 0         0         0.5       
OldLace                  0.992     0.96      0.9       
Olive                    0.5       0.5       0         
OliveDrab                0.42      0.556     0.136     
Orange                   1         0.648     0         
OrangeRed                1         0.27      0         
Orchid                   0.855     0.44      0.84      
PaleGoldenrod            0.932     0.91      0.668     
PaleGreen                0.596     0.985     0.596     
PaleTurquoise            0.688     0.932     0.932     
PaleVioletRed            0.86      0.44      0.576     
PapayaWhip               1         0.936     0.835     
PeachPuff                1         0.855     0.725     
Peru                     0.804     0.52      0.248     
Pink                     1         0.752     0.796     
Plum                     0.868     0.628     0.868     
PowderBlue               0.69      0.88      0.9       
Purple                   0.5       0         0.5       
Red                      1         0         0         
RosyBrown                0.736     0.56      0.56      
RoyalBlue                0.255     0.41      0.884     
SaddleBrown              0.545     0.27      0.075     
Salmon                   0.98      0.5       0.448     
SandyBrown               0.956     0.644     0.376     
SeaGreen                 0.18      0.545     0.34      
Seashell                 1         0.96      0.932     
Sienna                   0.628     0.32      0.176     
Silver                   0.752     0.752     0.752     
SkyBlue                  0.53      0.808     0.92      
SlateBlue                0.415     0.352     0.804     
SlateGray                0.44      0.5       0.565     
SlateGrey                0.44      0.5       0.565     
Snow                     1         0.98      0.98      
SpringGreen              0         1         0.498     
SteelBlue                0.275     0.51      0.705     
Tan                      0.824     0.705     0.55      
Teal                     0         0.5       0.5       
Thistle                  0.848     0.75      0.848     
Tomato                   1         0.39      0.28      
Turquoise                0.25      0.88      0.815     
Violet                   0.932     0.51      0.932     
VioletRed                0.816     0.125     0.565     
Wheat                    0.96      0.87      0.7       
White                    1         1         1         
WhiteSmoke               0.96      0.96      0.96      
Yellow                   1         1         0         
YellowGreen              0.604     0.804     0.196
```

#### `x11names`:

```
                         R         G         B
--------------------------------------------------
AntiqueWhite1            1         0.936     0.86      
AntiqueWhite2            0.932     0.875     0.8       
AntiqueWhite3            0.804     0.752     0.69      
AntiqueWhite4            0.545     0.512     0.47      
Aquamarine1              0.498     1         0.83      
Aquamarine2              0.464     0.932     0.776     
Aquamarine3              0.4       0.804     0.668     
Aquamarine4              0.27      0.545     0.455     
Azure1                   0.94      1         1         
Azure2                   0.88      0.932     0.932     
Azure3                   0.756     0.804     0.804     
Azure4                   0.512     0.545     0.545     
Bisque1                  1         0.894     0.77      
Bisque2                  0.932     0.835     0.716     
Bisque3                  0.804     0.716     0.62      
Bisque4                  0.545     0.49      0.42      
Blue1                    0         0         1         
Blue2                    0         0         0.932     
Blue3                    0         0         0.804     
Blue4                    0         0         0.545     
Brown1                   1         0.25      0.25      
Brown2                   0.932     0.23      0.23      
Brown3                   0.804     0.2       0.2       
Brown4                   0.545     0.136     0.136     
Burlywood1               1         0.828     0.608     
Burlywood2               0.932     0.772     0.57      
Burlywood3               0.804     0.668     0.49      
Burlywood4               0.545     0.45      0.332     
CadetBlue1               0.596     0.96      1         
CadetBlue2               0.556     0.898     0.932     
CadetBlue3               0.48      0.772     0.804     
CadetBlue4               0.325     0.525     0.545     
Chartreuse1              0.498     1         0         
Chartreuse2              0.464     0.932     0         
Chartreuse3              0.4       0.804     0         
Chartreuse4              0.27      0.545     0         
Chocolate1               1         0.498     0.14      
Chocolate2               0.932     0.464     0.13      
Chocolate3               0.804     0.4       0.112     
Chocolate4               0.545     0.27      0.075     
Coral1                   1         0.448     0.336     
Coral2                   0.932     0.415     0.312     
Coral3                   0.804     0.356     0.27      
Coral4                   0.545     0.244     0.185     
Cornsilk1                1         0.972     0.864     
Cornsilk2                0.932     0.91      0.804     
Cornsilk3                0.804     0.785     0.694     
Cornsilk4                0.545     0.532     0.47      
Cyan1                    0         1         1         
Cyan2                    0         0.932     0.932     
Cyan3                    0         0.804     0.804     
Cyan4                    0         0.545     0.545     
DarkGoldenrod1           1         0.725     0.06      
DarkGoldenrod2           0.932     0.68      0.055     
DarkGoldenrod3           0.804     0.585     0.048     
DarkGoldenrod4           0.545     0.396     0.03      
DarkOliveGreen1          0.792     1         0.44      
DarkOliveGreen2          0.736     0.932     0.408     
DarkOliveGreen3          0.635     0.804     0.352     
DarkOliveGreen4          0.43      0.545     0.24      
DarkOrange1              1         0.498     0         
DarkOrange2              0.932     0.464     0         
DarkOrange3              0.804     0.4       0         
DarkOrange4              0.545     0.27      0         
DarkOrchid1              0.75      0.244     1         
DarkOrchid2              0.698     0.228     0.932     
DarkOrchid3              0.604     0.196     0.804     
DarkOrchid4              0.408     0.132     0.545     
DarkSeaGreen1            0.756     1         0.756     
DarkSeaGreen2            0.705     0.932     0.705     
DarkSeaGreen3            0.608     0.804     0.608     
DarkSeaGreen4            0.41      0.545     0.41      
DarkSlateGray1           0.592     1         1         
DarkSlateGray2           0.552     0.932     0.932     
DarkSlateGray3           0.475     0.804     0.804     
DarkSlateGray4           0.32      0.545     0.545     
DeepPink1                1         0.08      0.576     
DeepPink2                0.932     0.07      0.536     
DeepPink3                0.804     0.064     0.464     
DeepPink4                0.545     0.04      0.312     
DeepSkyBlue1             0         0.75      1         
DeepSkyBlue2             0         0.698     0.932     
DeepSkyBlue3             0         0.604     0.804     
DeepSkyBlue4             0         0.408     0.545     
DodgerBlue1              0.116     0.565     1         
DodgerBlue2              0.11      0.525     0.932     
DodgerBlue3              0.094     0.455     0.804     
DodgerBlue4              0.064     0.305     0.545     
Firebrick1               1         0.19      0.19      
Firebrick2               0.932     0.172     0.172     
Firebrick3               0.804     0.15      0.15      
Firebrick4               0.545     0.1       0.1       
Gold1                    1         0.844     0         
Gold2                    0.932     0.79      0         
Gold3                    0.804     0.68      0         
Gold4                    0.545     0.46      0         
Goldenrod1               1         0.756     0.145     
Goldenrod2               0.932     0.705     0.132     
Goldenrod3               0.804     0.608     0.112     
Goldenrod4               0.545     0.41      0.08      
Green1                   0         1         0         
Green2                   0         0.932     0         
Green3                   0         0.804     0         
Green4                   0         0.545     0         
Honeydew1                0.94      1         0.94      
Honeydew2                0.88      0.932     0.88      
Honeydew3                0.756     0.804     0.756     
Honeydew4                0.512     0.545     0.512     
HotPink1                 1         0.43      0.705     
HotPink2                 0.932     0.415     0.655     
HotPink3                 0.804     0.376     0.565     
HotPink4                 0.545     0.228     0.385     
IndianRed1               1         0.415     0.415     
IndianRed2               0.932     0.39      0.39      
IndianRed3               0.804     0.332     0.332     
IndianRed4               0.545     0.228     0.228     
Ivory1                   1         1         0.94      
Ivory2                   0.932     0.932     0.88      
Ivory3                   0.804     0.804     0.756     
Ivory4                   0.545     0.545     0.512     
Khaki1                   1         0.965     0.56      
Khaki2                   0.932     0.9       0.52      
Khaki3                   0.804     0.776     0.45      
Khaki4                   0.545     0.525     0.305     
LavenderBlush1           1         0.94      0.96      
LavenderBlush2           0.932     0.88      0.898     
LavenderBlush3           0.804     0.756     0.772     
LavenderBlush4           0.545     0.512     0.525     
LemonChiffon1            1         0.98      0.804     
LemonChiffon2            0.932     0.912     0.75      
LemonChiffon3            0.804     0.79      0.648     
LemonChiffon4            0.545     0.536     0.44      
LightBlue1               0.75      0.936     1         
LightBlue2               0.698     0.875     0.932     
LightBlue3               0.604     0.752     0.804     
LightBlue4               0.408     0.512     0.545     
LightCyan1               0.88      1         1         
LightCyan2               0.82      0.932     0.932     
LightCyan3               0.705     0.804     0.804     
LightCyan4               0.48      0.545     0.545     
LightGoldenrod1          1         0.925     0.545     
LightGoldenrod2          0.932     0.864     0.51      
LightGoldenrod3          0.804     0.745     0.44      
LightGoldenrod4          0.545     0.505     0.298     
LightPink1               1         0.684     0.725     
LightPink2               0.932     0.635     0.68      
LightPink3               0.804     0.55      0.585     
LightPink4               0.545     0.372     0.396     
LightSalmon1             1         0.628     0.48      
LightSalmon2             0.932     0.585     0.448     
LightSalmon3             0.804     0.505     0.385     
LightSalmon4             0.545     0.34      0.26      
LightSkyBlue1            0.69      0.888     1         
LightSkyBlue2            0.644     0.828     0.932     
LightSkyBlue3            0.552     0.712     0.804     
LightSkyBlue4            0.376     0.484     0.545     
LightSteelBlue1          0.792     0.884     1         
LightSteelBlue2          0.736     0.824     0.932     
LightSteelBlue3          0.635     0.71      0.804     
LightSteelBlue4          0.43      0.484     0.545     
LightYellow1             1         1         0.88      
LightYellow2             0.932     0.932     0.82      
LightYellow3             0.804     0.804     0.705     
LightYellow4             0.545     0.545     0.48      
Magenta1                 1         0         1         
Magenta2                 0.932     0         0.932     
Magenta3                 0.804     0         0.804     
Magenta4                 0.545     0         0.545     
Maroon1                  1         0.204     0.7       
Maroon2                  0.932     0.19      0.655     
Maroon3                  0.804     0.16      0.565     
Maroon4                  0.545     0.11      0.385     
MediumOrchid1            0.88      0.4       1         
MediumOrchid2            0.82      0.372     0.932     
MediumOrchid3            0.705     0.32      0.804     
MediumOrchid4            0.48      0.215     0.545     
MediumPurple1            0.67      0.51      1         
MediumPurple2            0.624     0.475     0.932     
MediumPurple3            0.536     0.408     0.804     
MediumPurple4            0.365     0.28      0.545     
MistyRose1               1         0.894     0.884     
MistyRose2               0.932     0.835     0.824     
MistyRose3               0.804     0.716     0.71      
MistyRose4               0.545     0.49      0.484     
NavajoWhite1             1         0.87      0.68      
NavajoWhite2             0.932     0.81      0.63      
NavajoWhite3             0.804     0.7       0.545     
NavajoWhite4             0.545     0.475     0.37      
OliveDrab1               0.752     1         0.244     
OliveDrab2               0.7       0.932     0.228     
OliveDrab3               0.604     0.804     0.196     
OliveDrab4               0.41      0.545     0.132     
Orange1                  1         0.648     0         
Orange2                  0.932     0.604     0         
Orange3                  0.804     0.52      0         
Orange4                  0.545     0.352     0         
OrangeRed1               1         0.27      0         
OrangeRed2               0.932     0.25      0         
OrangeRed3               0.804     0.215     0         
OrangeRed4               0.545     0.145     0         
Orchid1                  1         0.512     0.98      
Orchid2                  0.932     0.48      0.912     
Orchid3                  0.804     0.41      0.79      
Orchid4                  0.545     0.28      0.536     
PaleGreen1               0.604     1         0.604     
PaleGreen2               0.565     0.932     0.565     
PaleGreen3               0.488     0.804     0.488     
PaleGreen4               0.33      0.545     0.33      
PaleTurquoise1           0.732     1         1         
PaleTurquoise2           0.684     0.932     0.932     
PaleTurquoise3           0.59      0.804     0.804     
PaleTurquoise4           0.4       0.545     0.545     
PaleVioletRed1           1         0.51      0.67      
PaleVioletRed2           0.932     0.475     0.624     
PaleVioletRed3           0.804     0.408     0.536     
PaleVioletRed4           0.545     0.28      0.365     
PeachPuff1               1         0.855     0.725     
PeachPuff2               0.932     0.796     0.68      
PeachPuff3               0.804     0.688     0.585     
PeachPuff4               0.545     0.468     0.396     
Pink1                    1         0.71      0.772     
Pink2                    0.932     0.664     0.72      
Pink3                    0.804     0.57      0.62      
Pink4                    0.545     0.39      0.424     
Plum1                    1         0.732     1         
Plum2                    0.932     0.684     0.932     
Plum3                    0.804     0.59      0.804     
Plum4                    0.545     0.4       0.545     
Purple1                  0.608     0.19      1         
Purple2                  0.57      0.172     0.932     
Purple3                  0.49      0.15      0.804     
Purple4                  0.332     0.1       0.545     
Red1                     1         0         0         
Red2                     0.932     0         0         
Red3                     0.804     0         0         
Red4                     0.545     0         0         
RosyBrown1               1         0.756     0.756     
RosyBrown2               0.932     0.705     0.705     
RosyBrown3               0.804     0.608     0.608     
RosyBrown4               0.545     0.41      0.41      
RoyalBlue1               0.284     0.464     1         
RoyalBlue2               0.264     0.43      0.932     
RoyalBlue3               0.228     0.372     0.804     
RoyalBlue4               0.152     0.25      0.545     
Salmon1                  1         0.55      0.41      
Salmon2                  0.932     0.51      0.385     
Salmon3                  0.804     0.44      0.33      
Salmon4                  0.545     0.298     0.224     
SeaGreen1                0.33      1         0.624     
SeaGreen2                0.305     0.932     0.58      
SeaGreen3                0.264     0.804     0.5       
SeaGreen4                0.18      0.545     0.34      
Seashell1                1         0.96      0.932     
Seashell2                0.932     0.898     0.87      
Seashell3                0.804     0.772     0.75      
Seashell4                0.545     0.525     0.51      
Sienna1                  1         0.51      0.28      
Sienna2                  0.932     0.475     0.26      
Sienna3                  0.804     0.408     0.224     
Sienna4                  0.545     0.28      0.15      
SkyBlue1                 0.53      0.808     1         
SkyBlue2                 0.494     0.752     0.932     
SkyBlue3                 0.424     0.65      0.804     
SkyBlue4                 0.29      0.44      0.545     
SlateBlue1               0.512     0.435     1         
SlateBlue2               0.48      0.404     0.932     
SlateBlue3               0.41      0.35      0.804     
SlateBlue4               0.28      0.235     0.545     
SlateGray1               0.776     0.888     1         
SlateGray2               0.725     0.828     0.932     
SlateGray3               0.624     0.712     0.804     
SlateGray4               0.424     0.484     0.545     
Snow1                    1         0.98      0.98      
Snow2                    0.932     0.912     0.912     
Snow3                    0.804     0.79      0.79      
Snow4                    0.545     0.536     0.536     
SpringGreen1             0         1         0.498     
SpringGreen2             0         0.932     0.464     
SpringGreen3             0         0.804     0.4       
SpringGreen4             0         0.545     0.27      
SteelBlue1               0.39      0.72      1         
SteelBlue2               0.36      0.675     0.932     
SteelBlue3               0.31      0.58      0.804     
SteelBlue4               0.21      0.392     0.545     
Tan1                     1         0.648     0.31      
Tan2                     0.932     0.604     0.288     
Tan3                     0.804     0.52      0.248     
Tan4                     0.545     0.352     0.17      
Thistle1                 1         0.884     1         
Thistle2                 0.932     0.824     0.932     
Thistle3                 0.804     0.71      0.804     
Thistle4                 0.545     0.484     0.545     
Tomato1                  1         0.39      0.28      
Tomato2                  0.932     0.36      0.26      
Tomato3                  0.804     0.31      0.224     
Tomato4                  0.545     0.21      0.15      
Turquoise1               0         0.96      1         
Turquoise2               0         0.898     0.932     
Turquoise3               0         0.772     0.804     
Turquoise4               0         0.525     0.545     
VioletRed1               1         0.244     0.59      
VioletRed2               0.932     0.228     0.55      
VioletRed3               0.804     0.196     0.47      
VioletRed4               0.545     0.132     0.32      
Wheat1                   1         0.905     0.73      
Wheat2                   0.932     0.848     0.684     
Wheat3                   0.804     0.73      0.59      
Wheat4                   0.545     0.494     0.4       
Yellow1                  1         1         0         
Yellow2                  0.932     0.932     0         
Yellow3                  0.804     0.804     0         
Yellow4                  0.545     0.545     0         
Gray0                    0.745     0.745     0.745     
Green0                   0         1         0         
Grey0                    0.745     0.745     0.745     
Maroon0                  0.69      0.19      0.376     
Purple0                  0.628     0.125     0.94
```

Comment: The `x11names` offers many choices indeed! If I write `\usepackage{xcolor}` in my preamble, I can use the basic colours. However, if instead I use `\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}`, I get the error "Option clash for package xcolor"

Comment: @User17670: Try moving the `\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}` to be before any other package that loads `xcolor` (which `pstricks` is probably doing).